# Two bluetoothed androids

Tags: android, bluetooth

What can you get from an Android phone if it’s connected by Bluetooth to another Android phone? And what would they do to get it? Step-by-step instructions please I’m slow at this.

Comment: What do you mean "get"? How are they connected? Please note that we aren't a hacking forum. We won't teach people how to hack.